# Good javascript event calendar using YUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, yui

Has anyone come across an Events Calendar (e.g. shows events on a calendar format rather than allowing user to choose date) that uses YUI as its base?  I have found some based on jquery, but I am trying to standardise my stuff to YUI so wondering if anyone has any there, I can't seem to find one on YUI pages.

Otherwise a recommendation of the best jquery one would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with YUI's options in this area I can wholeheartedly endorse the JQuery based FullCalendar solution. It's a very full-featured and stable project. See [here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) for more details.